# How should I model a group relation in the database and in OOP?

Tags: oop, database-design, data-modeling, erp

I have instances of `Item` that I would like to have in groups `ItemGroup`. But if an `Item` is moved to another itemgroup, I would like to keep track of the change for accountability reasons. E.g. I need to know if an `Item` was in one `ItemGroup` in October and another in September.

How should I model this in the database? How should I model this in my classes, OOP? I can see a few different solutions, but they are all complicated in some way so I don't know how to implement it.

Either I could go with three tables, `Item` `ItemGroup` `GroupRelation` and keep an timestamp on the `GroupRelation`. If the item information is updated I need to create a new item, and a new GroupRelation. If the Item changes group I have to create a new GroupRelation. And if the Group information is changed I have to create a new Group and a new GroupRelation. It is complex since I have to create multiple new objects on change.

```
Item
+----+---------+-----+------+
| id | item_nr | ean | name |
+----+---------+-----+------+

ItemGroup
+----+------------+-----+
| id | group_name | vat |
+----+------------+-----+

GroupRelation
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
| id | item_id | group_id | timestamp |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
```

An alternative solution could be to have only two classes `Item` and `ItemGroup` but then I need to have a timestamp in both of them so I know when they are changed. If Group is updated, I have to update all Items that belongs to that group, so this is also complex.

```
Item
+----+---------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
| id | item_nr | ean | name | group_id | timestamp |
+----+---------+-----+------+----------+-----------+

ItemGroup
+----+------------+-----+-----------+
| id | group_name | vat | timestamp |
+----+------------+-----+-----------+
```

And there is probably other solutions, one is maybe to move old verions to another table. But then is it complex to search for data when both current and old data should be looked up. Or I could have a column `prev_id` that link to the old version.

Is there anyone that have experience of similar datamodels and has any recommendation? Is there any best practices for this kind of problem?

Comment: I'm not following some of your logic. Why would you have to create a new item/group when some of its information is updated?

Comment: @Joe: For accountability reasons. The old version has to be saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with your `Item`, `ItemGroup` and `GroupRelation` as a good normalized design with minimum duplication.

Your auditing requirement can be modeled with an additional table for each table you need to audit (for example: `ItemAudit`, `ItemGroupAudit`) which holds the fields you need to audit and a timestamp. You populate the audit table every time an auditable field changes.

That way, you have a historical record and don't encumber your day to day tables with historical data.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Do I need an `GroupRelationAudit` too? I think so. How about the OO-design, I think it should be enough with two classes `Item` and `ItemGroup` even if I have three tables `Item`, `ItemGroup` and `GroupRelation` or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: @Jonas - I can't tell you what you need. If you need to audit the `GroupRelation`, then yes, you probably need that too. As for the OO design, `Item` and `ItemGroup` objects should be enough (so long as one has a reference on the other). You may also want collections on each for the historical data.

Comment: Ah, that sounds great. I could keep the `ItemAudit`-instances in a collection in `Item`.

Comment: @Jonas - that's the idea. Perhaps use lazy loading, so you don't get all the data if you don't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I think there is a concept of a `GroupRelationHistory` which exists implicitly in your model. I would make it to an own entity like `Item`, `ItemGroup` and `GroupRelation`.

In the object world I would make `Item` to be aware of its `GroupRelationHistory`, meaning that an `Item` object has a reference to `GroupRelationHistory` object. Essentially `GroupRelationHistory` is just a list of zero, one or more `GroupRelation`s.

Introducing this concept should be backed up by real business needs. Go to your customer (or some representative) and ask if the history is an entity of its own right and has some business value. If yes, think about this approach and refine it according to the business needs. Then think about the database model, which highly depends on the specific refinements. If no, then I would make the history concept a pure auditing feature like [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) suggested.